# Is it possible to get a list of tracks from the entire spotify library?

Tags: javascript, spotify

Is it possible to get a list of tracks from the entire spotify library?

I'm looking for something like:

```
library.tracks
```

but instead of getting just the tracks from the user's library, I want tracks from the whole spotify library (or at least all the songs available in their region).

Thanks for your help.

Edit: I'm trying to use the Spotify API to create an application that finds and plays a random song in the Spotify library.

Comment: I really doubt it.  Why would they allow you to download their entire database?

Comment: I'm sorry if my question was unclear - I don't want to download their database.  I'm trying to create an application that chooses and plays a random song from all of spotify so I wanted access to a list of tracks to play.

Comment: @JonathanHsu - Did you ever finish this project? I would also love to play totally random songs from Spotify's entire catalogue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way of getting a list of all the 15+ million tracks in the library.
But you could probably create some kind of random feature anyway:

1. Randomize a character (e.g A-Z) or word (i.e. by using some kind of dictionary).
2. Do a track/artist/album search in the Spotify library using your character/word and pick a random song from the search results.

Don't know how "random" you want it, but that's one way of doing it anyway.